# Adding properties to enums in JOOQ

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, jooq

We have been moving away from hibernate to jooq for months now.  Pattern we would often do in Hibernate would be writing a custom enum like this...

```
public enum HBMCapacityType {

    Accepting("Accepting until end of day", true),
    Limited("Limited until end of day", true),
    AtCapacity("At Capacity until further notice",false);

    private final String description;
    private final boolean userOverridable;

    HBMCapacityType(String description, boolean userOverridable) {
        this.description = description;
        this.userOverridable = userOverridable;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public boolean isUserOverridable() {
        return this.userOverridable;
    }
}
```

Then we are able to use this a column in our hibernate domain objects

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Type(type = "pg_enum")
@Column(name = "capacity_type", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "capacity_type")
private HBMCapacityType capacityType;
```

This is convenient as we can call capacityType.getDescription() when rendering to to the  GUI.  We have this nice 1:1 mapping of enum types to a description we can use in the GUI.  Sometimes we have multiple getters like this say one for description and a few booleans which characterize behaviour associated with that enum.  The property isUserOverrideable would be an example of this.

Now looking at JOOQ: since this was defined as an enum in postgres JOOQ automatically generates a type like this...

```
/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public enum CapacityType implements EnumType {

    Accepting("Accepting"),

    Limited("Limited"),

    AtCapacity("AtCapacity");

    private final String literal;

    private CapacityType(String literal) {
        this.literal = literal;
    }

    @Override
    public Catalog getCatalog() {
        return getSchema().getCatalog();
    }

    @Override
    public Schema getSchema() {
        return Wastecoordinator.WASTECOORDINATOR;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "capacity_type";
    }

    @Override
    public String getLiteral() {
        return literal;
    }

    /**
     * Lookup a value of this EnumType by its literal
     */
    public static CapacityType lookupLiteral(String literal) {
        return EnumType.lookupLiteral(CapacityType.class, literal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your question is about how to add custom properties to jOOQ generated enums? There are multiple approaches:

#### Using a custom code section

One way to achieve the same functionality is by adding [a custom code section as described here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/). You'll add a `generateEnumClassFooter()` method to your own `JavaGenerator` subclass, and generate the necessary code there. Unlike in your original code, you can't modify the properties of enum values, so you'll just have to switch over `this`, instead.

#### Move the logic outside of the enum

You can always just write a static utility of the form

```java
public static boolean isUserOverridable(HBMCapacityType type) {
    return switch (type) { ... };
}
```

It's less object oriented, but maybe, that doesn't matter all that much?

#### Keep 2 separate enums

You don't have to use jOOQ's enum. You can translate it to your own hand-written enum and [attach an `EnumConverter` to your  generated code](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-enum-converter/) to map between the jOOQ enum type and yours.